# git difference between fetch branch vs fetch branch:branch

Tags: git, git-fetch

I am confused about

`git fetch origin master` vs `git fetch origin master:master`.

I know first will fetch from repository and specified branch.

what about second `git fetch origin master:master`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument you're varying in these examples is called the `refspec`.

In the first example, you're using a shorthand that specifies the source ref to fetch (`master`) but does not specify a target ref to update.  Default behavior would apply, which with a typical setup means `origin/master` would be updated.

The second example, you provide a source (`master`), then a `:` to separate that from a destination, then a destination (also `master`).  This will attempt to directly update the *local* `master` branch of your local repo - rather than the `origin/master` remote branch ref.  It may fail (e.g. if the local repo is a non-bare repo in a default configuration, and it has `master` checked out).

If you want to use explicit refspec but you still want to update the remote ref, you could say

```
git fetch origin master:origin/master
```